# How do I emit static extern method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

I am trying to dynamically generate an assembly with P/Invoke methods.

This is what I am doing now:

```
var pinvoke = implementationBuilder.DefineMethod(methodInfo.Name,
    MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.PinvokeImpl,
    methodInfo.ReturnType,
    parameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());
pinvoke.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(DllImportCtor,
    constructorArgs: new object[]{libraryPath},
    namedFields: new []{CallingConventionField},
    fieldValues: dllImportFieldValues));
```

However, I get "Method 'MethodName' in type '...' does not have an implementation."

How to properly emit what C# would for `[DllImport("42")] static extern void MethodName(IntPtr a);`?

Comment: @Charles This is not really relevant, as this question is about generating PInvokes at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DefineMethod` simply adds a method to a type.

You would instead use [TypeBuilder.DefinePInvokeMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definepinvokemethod?view=netframework-4.8) or one of its overloads

> Defines a PInvoke method given its name, the name of the DLL in which
>   the method is defined, the attributes of the method, the calling
>   convention of the method, the return type of the method, the types of
>   the parameters of the method, and the PInvoke flags.

**Example**

```
Type[] paramTypes = { typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(int) };

MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefinePInvokeMethod(
        methodName,
        DllName,
        MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.PinvokeImpl,
        CallingConventions.Standard,
        typeof(int),
        paramTypes, // what ever you want here
        CallingConvention.Winapi,
        CharSet.Ansi);
```

> **parameterTypes**
>
> `Type[]` The types of the method's parameters.

Comment: how about an example with parameters

Comment: this is interesting, how about params with ref, in / out, or callbacks (i guess this one is trickier)

Comment: @Charles yes it does, however you can marshal the usual ways. and use pointers

Comment: HM, only available in .NET Standard 2.1 :(

Comment: @LOST you should be able to do this in other ways though, i just thought this was the easiest approach. Maybe you want to keep this question open